# Deployed C# application requires Windows 8.1 and Universal CRT SDKs

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I have a C# application in Visual Studio which consists of a C++ project targeted for Windows SDK Version 8.1. This project also requires the Windows Universal CRT SDK to build. The Visual Studio Installer allows one to install these components individually. So everything runs as expected on this PC. However, when I deploy it to a PC without the SDKs installed, exceptions are thrown when the C++ dll is called. I thought the whole point of deploying a standalone applications is to have everything contained once built, without requiring additional SDKs. Is there a build option I am missing?

It doesn't seem super straight forward to download and install the SDKs individually either. The easiest way is to download Visual Studio and install them similarly to the development PC, which also requires a bare-bones version of Visual Studio. This isn't a huge problem but rather in convenient.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is the SDK statically or dynamically linked?

Comment: Also, SDKs sometimes will have a binary you can package with your software. Then your deployment software can make sure it gets installed if it isn't already.

Comment: Does the target PC have VS redistributables?

Comment: Seams like they are dynamically linked... That might be the problem. I didn't write the C++ project. How can I find out? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Yes, they have the same VS redistributables installed.

Comment: The UCRT is an operating system component, it is delivered through Windows Update.

Comment: Static linking is so everything is in one big executable. Dynamic linking is so that it gets linked at run time. This provides more flexibility. What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks to the tips and leading me to look at the linking. Turns out c++ project was using an additional dynamic dll I didn't know about. Turns out there is a static version which fixed the issue. Thank you!